# Conditional length of a binary data series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Having a DataFrame with the following column:

```
df['A'] = [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]
```

What would be the best vectorized way to control the length of "1"-series by some limiting value? Let's say the limit is 2, then the resulting column 'B' must look like:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  0
3  0  0
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  1  0
7  1  0
8  0  0
9  1  1
```

Comment: So to be clear: whenever there is a run of more than a certain number of 1's in the column, you want to cut off that run at the certain number and replace the rest of the run with zeros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fully-vectorized solution is to use the `shift`-`groupby`-`cumsum`-`cumcount` combination<sup>1</sup> to indicate where consecutive runs are shorter than 2 (or whatever limiting value you like). Then, `&` this new boolean Series with the original column:

```
df['B'] = ((df.groupby((df.A != df.A.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() <= 1) & df.A)\
          .astype(int) # cast the boolean Series back to integers
```

This produces the new column in the DataFrame:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  0
3  0  0
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  1  0
7  1  0
8  0  0
9  1  1
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See the [pandas cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#grouping); the section on grouping, "Grouping like Python’s itertools.groupby"

Answer (score 2):

Another way (checking if previous two are 1):

```
In [443]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]})

In [444]: limit = 2

In [445]: df['B'] = map(lambda x: df['A'][x] if x < limit else int(not all(y == 1 for y in df['A'][x - limit:x])), range(len(df)))

In [446]: df
Out[446]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  0
3  0  0
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  1  0
7  1  0
8  0  0
9  1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the values in the series will all be either `0` or `1`, I think you can use a little trick involving convolution. Make a copy of your column (which need not be a Pandas object, it can just be a normal Numpy array)

```
a = df['A'].as_matrix()
```

and convolve it with a sequence of 1's that is one longer than the `cutoff` you want, then chop off the last `cutoff` elements. E.g. for a `cutoff` of 2, you would do

```
long_run_count = numpy.convolve(a, [1, 1, 1])[:-2]
```

The resulting array, in this case, gives the number of `1`'s that occur in the 3 elements prior to and including that element. If that number is 3, then you are in a run that has exceeded length 2. So just set those elements to zero.

```
a[long_run_count > 2] = 0
```

You can now assign the resulting array to a new column in your `DataFrame`.

```
df['B'] = a
```

To turn this into a more general method:

```
def trim_runs(array, cutoff):
    a = numpy.asarray(array)
    a[numpy.convolve(a, numpy.ones(cutoff + 1))[:-cutoff] > cutoff] = 0
    return a
```